# How do I customize hierarchical breadcrumbs?

Tags: 8, navigation, breadcrumbs

The breadcrumbs I get are like the following ones.

- Home / services
- Home / service 1
- Home / service 2

I want to change them to the following ones.

- Home / services
- Homes / services / service 1
- Homes / services / service 2

How can I change the breadcrumbs to be the way I want them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In D8 the hierarchy of breadcrumbs is by default path based, so you have to change the path for the second level from `/service1` to `/services/service1`

Or install a module to build the hierarchy based on menus or taxonomy terms:

https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_breadcrumb
https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_breadcrumb

Comment: +1 for menu breadcrumb. My best advice on breadcrumbs is to make it structure based and not try to inject things to the crumb chain that really do not exist. Menu makes it easy. Views should play nice too, if not, it is easy to alter for them.

Comment: what about  https://www.drupal.org/project/easy_breadcrumb ?